# google-map-react not loading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, gatsby

My Google Map gives following error:
"*Oops! Something went wrong. This page didn't load Google Maps correctly. See the JavaScript console for technical details.*"
I use Gatsby and google-map-react package. My code:

```
const AnyReactComponent = ({ text }) => <div>{text}</div>;

static defaultProps = {
    center: {
        lat: 59.95,
        lng: 30.33
    },
    zoom: 11
};

<div style={{ height: '50vh', width: '100%' }}>
    <GoogleMapReact
        bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: "https://maps.google.com/maps?q=manhatan&t=&z=13&ie=UTF8&iwloc=&output=embed" }}
        defaultCenter={this.props.center}
        defaultZoom={this.props.zoom}
    >
        <AnyReactComponent
            lat={59.955413}
            lng={30.337844}
            text="My Marker"
        />
    </GoogleMapReact>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In bootstrapURLKeys you have to add google map api key not url.
you can get key from google console https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

```
 <GoogleMapReact
    bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: /* YOUR KEY HERE */ }}
    ......
  />
```

Comment: dont add your API key direct to a file if being saved in version control!!!